# How I should name the layout for 1920x1080 pixels and 5,5 inches device?

Tags: android, layout

I want to create a special layout for a device with 1920x1080 pixel and with 5,5 inches.

Does anyone know how I have to name my layout for this?

Now I have for example for the Nexus 10 a layout named **layout-sw720dp**

I found anytime a calculator for this, but I cant find it anymore.

thx.

Comment: you can use only one layout for any phone screen size . use 'layout'.

Comment: You can point this `layout` by either `layout-sw720dp` or by `layout-xlarge`. For more information regarding how to use this you can read : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

So first you need to understand what's the meaning behind `layout-sw720dp`
Based on [Android Documentation on Supporting Multiple Screen](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts) `sw` mean smallestWidth and the format is layout-swdp.

so 720 the fundamental size of a screen, as indicated by the shortest dimension of the available screen area. Specifically, the device's smallestWidth is the shortest of the screen's available height and width (you may also think of it as the "smallest possible width" for the screen). You can use this qualifier to ensure that, regardless of the screen's current orientation, your application's has at least  dps of width available for its UI.

For example, if your layout requires that its smallest dimension of screen area be at least 720 dp at all times, then you can use this qualifer to create the layout resources, res/layout-sw720dp/. The system will use these resources only when the smallest dimension of available screen is at least 720dp, regardless of whether the 720dp side is the user-perceived height or width. The smallestWidth is a fixed screen size characteristic of the device; the device's smallestWidth does not change when the screen's orientation changes